# C# WPF DataBinding "Can't find Property"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm still trying to get my head around databinding in WPF and so I'm having a bit of a problem working out how to solve this issue for the past 10 hours:

I have an object named birdList which consist of a list of Bird Objects(bird1 and bird2). I have made all properties within the objects public. When I try to data bind the Common_Name property to a TextBlock I get nothing. Looking at the output in Visual Studio I see the following Errors/Warnings:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=47755470): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=47755470): Activate with root item 'birdList'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=47755470):   At level 0 - for String.Bird found accessor <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=47755470):   At level 0 - for EnumerableCollectionView.Bird found accessor <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=47755470):   At level 0 - for Char.Bird found accessor <null>

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Bird' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-874795121)'.

System.Windows.Data Warning: 103 : BindingExpression (hash=47755470): Replace item at level 1 with {NullDataItem}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=47755470): TransferValue - using fallback/default value ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=47755470): TransferValue - using final value ''
```

C# Code:

```
    public Birds birdList { get; set; }

    Bird bird1 { get; set; }
    Bird bird2 { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        birdList = new Birds();

        bird1 = new Bird();
        bird2 = new Bird();

        bird1.Common_Name = "Mallard";
        bird2.Common_Name = "Red-winged Blackbird";

        birdList.Bird.Add(bird1);
        birdList.Bird.Add(bird2);

        birdList.Test = "Testing!";

        this.DataContext = this;

        this.Photos = (PhotoCollection)(Application.Current.FindResource("Photos") as ObjectDataProvider).Data;
        this.Photos.Path = "E:\\Network Drive\\SarDonnie's Documents - Networked\\Birds\\Ducks, Geese, and Swans (Anatidae)\\Mallard\\Clear Lake Bay Park 1-18-16";

    }

public class Birds
{
    public string Test { get; set; }

    public List<Bird> _Birds = new List<Bird>();
    public List<Bird> Bird
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Birds;
        }
    }
}

public class Bird
{

    public string Common_Name { get; set; }

}
```

XMAL:

```
        <Grid  Grid.Column="2">
            <ContentControl Content="birdList">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Height="50" Text="{Binding Bird.Common_Name,diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>
        </Grid>
```

I have also tried this to test accessing the Test property inside the birdList Object:

```
<Grid  Grid.Column="2">
            <ContentControl Content="birdList">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Height="50" Text="{Binding Test>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>
        </Grid>
```

**My question is why can't I seem to find the birdList.Bird.Common_Name property or the birdList.Test property?**

Thanks!

Also feel free to point me to some good sites that house information on WPF. I hate banging my head on this keyboard and getting no where!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

1. You need to tell the path of the "list" to xaml (via "ItemsSource" property).
2. Use controls that accept collections such as ListBox.

Here's my code:

- MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Bird> Birds { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Birds = new List<Bird>();

        var bird1 = new Bird();
        bird1.CommonName = "Mallard";
        Birds.Add(bird1);

        var bird2 = new Bird();
        bird2.CommonName = "Red-winged Blackbird";
        Birds.Add(bird2);

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public class Bird
    {
        public string CommonName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Birds}" DisplayMemberPath="CommonName" />
</Grid>
```

**EDIT**

If you need to update from the code on runtime, follow Jai's advice. I only showed the minimal solution for the question.

**EDIT2**

Always remember to use **properties** in binding, or else it won't work.

```
public class Birds
{
    public string Test { get; set; }

    //Binding source must be a property!!
    public List<Bird> _Birds { get; set; } = new List<Bird>();
    public List<Bird> Bird
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Birds;
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding birdList._Birds}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! 

Implementing your code works, however, I'm really puzzled how one form of my code didn't work. Like I said I worked on it for 10 hours. 

So at one point I was using a DataGrid with the ItemSource="{Bindng birdList._Birds}".

birdList._Birds is a list of birds, but it won't display! This would be equivalent to your code, but for some reason it isn't. The only thing I can think of is maybe my syntax is off. How can I access my birdList._Birds list?

Comment: Did you bind the property that you want to display to the DataGrid?

Comment: To bind I used: <DataGrid ItemSource="{Bindng birdList._Birds}">. Within my MainWindow I created an object named birdList and added 2 Bird Objects to it(see original post). The DataContext was set to: this.DataContext = this. Where "this" is my MainWindow which includes the created birdList object. Maybe I'm missing a binding step or since the binding is one way the steps I'm using to bind are out of order? Or I could have the syntax wrong? Especially this line could be wrong sice I am trying to access a list of objects inside another object:<DataGrid ItemSource="{Bindng birdList._Birds}">

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I get it! Wow what a relief to final have it working and understand how it works. You truly rock! Thanks again. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there are quite a bit of problem out there.

Firstly, you have a list of birds, but you only have one `TextBlock` to display it. If you have manually made multiple `TextBlock` (which you didn't show us), then there is no point to make a list of birds, because it means that your view is aware exactly how many birds there are (in your viewmodel???). Therefore, Doncot is right to say that you should use a `ListBox`, or any other controls that allow you to display a list of items.

Secondly, if you want to use a `ListBox` (or something similar), you would need to have to consider your list of birds. Binding is always related to `INotifyPropetyChanged`, `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `DependencyProperty`. Creating a class just to hold your list does not seem necessary, unless you have other special requirements that we are not aware of.

Doncot is quite near there, but I want to touch a little more. Using a `List<Bird>` works fine, except that your `ListBox` would not know it needs to update itself when the list is modified later. This is because that `List<Bird>` does not notify the Binding engine when a change occurs.

If you implement this together with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, your binding would be able to trigger when the whole `List<Bird>` is being re-instantiated (i.e. `Birds = new List<Bird>();`). This is normally not what you want, either.

If you change the whole `List<Bird>` into `ObservableCollection<Bird>`, your binding will trigger when you do `Birds.Add(new Bird());`. This is because `ObservableCollection<>` is an implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, which you may also choose to implement it on your own. Up to this point, your binding is pretty solid, except that it does not know when a `Bird` within that list is being modified.

Consider this:

```
Birds.ElementAt(0).Common_Name = "New Bird Name!";
```

The collection itself is not being modified, because it is still holding to the reference of the same `Bird` instance. Therefore, the Binding engine will not be aware of this change. To solve this, your `Bird` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well, which is similar to what vishakh369 answered.

Comment: Thanks for the additional input! It really helped me understand binding at a deeper level. BTW: I was using a DataGrid before, but by 200 iterations I was trying random stuff I found online (Sometimes I get desperate). Additionally, I added a comment above let me know if you know the answer.  Thanks ^_^